# Declaring a variable is causing my code to fail to run

Tags: php

```
<html>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "4242";
$dbname = "myDB";
$table = "exercises";
$date = date("Y,m,d");
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password, $dbname);

if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "insert into $table (name, exercise, number,date) values ($_POST['name'],$_POST['exercise'],$_POST['number'],$date)";





?>
<body>
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
The number you picked was <?php echo $_POST["number"]; ?> on <?php echo        date("Y/m/d") ?><br>

    </body>

</html>
```

The problem seems to be declaring $sql. If I declare comment out the line like this

```
$sql = "insert into $table (name, exercise, number,date) values "//($_POST['name'],$_POST['exercise'],$_POST['number'],$date)";
```

It works fine. And I can't figure out why this is working this way. I'm doing this as a learning project.

Comment: why don't you have `.` between the sql query and the commented code ?

Comment: What error(s) are you seeing?  What happens when it "fails"?

Comment: I need a . between the sql query and commented code? I just added "// to test it was all one string.

I'm not sure where to look for errors, in the page I get

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in `$sql`.

First, you need quotes around the strings in the `VALUES` clause. Second, you need to put `{ }` around array references so you can use quotes in the index.

```
$sql = "insert into $table (name, exercise, number,date) values ('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['exercise']}',{$_POST['number']},'$date')";
```

However, `mysqli` supports parametrized queries, and it would be better to use that, to prevent SQL injection.

```
$sql = "insert into $table (name, exercise, number,date) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssis", $_POST['name'], $_POST['exercise'], $_POST['number'], $date);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: thanks do you mind explaining `bind_param("ssis",` the rest I think I understand.

Comment: `ssis` means `string, string, integer, string`. Isn't that explained clearly in the manual? I was just guessing which of the fields are which datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple understanding of concatenation and usage of variables inside a PHP string is enough to answer your question.

**Query:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (name, exercise, number,date)
        VALUES (
           '".$_POST['name']."' 
          ,'".$_POST['exercise']."'
          ,'".$_POST['number']."'
          ,'$date')";
```

If you want to go with a `mysqli` way of doing  the query, just bind the values to a variable through `bind_param`